# Calculation of total flux through an inverted hemisphere for a vector field in spherical unit vectors

Tags: spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

Here is a question which I came across recently

> Calculate the flux of the vector field $\vec{v} = r\cos\theta (\hat{r}) + r\sin\theta (\hat{\theta}) + r\sin\theta \cos\phi (\hat{\phi})$ over an inverted hemisphere of radius $R$ with its base on the $x\text{-}y$ plane and centred at the origin.

Using *Gauss's Divergence Theorem*, I can easily calculate the flux through the entire surface. But I wish to calculate it using the normal definition- $\iint  \vec{v}\cdot d\vec{A}$ over the closed surface $S$. Now, $S$ can be written as an union of two boundaries $\{S_{1} \cup S_{2}\}$, where $S_{1}$ would be the outer bounding surface, and $S_{2}$ would be the bounding circle in the $x\text{-}y$ plane. Calculating the flux through through $S_{1}$, I get the value as $\frac{2\pi r^{3}}{3}$. I had taken the unit normal vector $\hat{n}$ to be $\hat{r}$ for $S_{1}$, but this won't work for $S_{2}$. The unit normal vector for $S_{2}$ would be $-\hat{k}$ in Cartesian coordinates, so I changed it to unit vectors in spherical coordinates, as the vector field $\vec{v}$ is also in the spherical unit vectors. But after that, I can't work out the surface integral through $S_{2}$. The answer should be $\frac{5\pi r^{3}}{3}$, as obtained from the *Gauss's Divergence Theorem*, but I'm not being able to reach that. Can someone please guide me how to proceed from here? I'm still just learning these things!

**PS**: Please don't discard this question as a repeated one. It's true that there have been questions before on this forum related to flux through a hemisphere, but in most of them, the vector fields were in Cartesian coordinates and it was easy to work with. I found a few answers on the spherical unit vectors, but they didn't include the flux due to the bounding circle in $x\text{-}y$ plane, for any reason whatsoever!

Comment: You mean the bounding disc, not the bounding circle.  And the question is asking for the flux across the hemisphere $S_1$ so why bother with closing it with $S_2$?.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{5\pi r^{3}}{3}$. This indicates that I need to include the flux through $S_{2}$ as well, I guess.

Comment: Divergence theorem gives me the answer, but I want to verify this using the conventional method as well. Integrating over $S_{1}$ gives me $\frac{2\pi r^{3}}{3}$, if I've done it correctly.

Comment: On $S_2$, you have $\theta=\pi/2$ and $\hat\theta=-\hat{k}$ (assuming "physicist" convention $(x,y,z)=(r\sin\theta\cos\phi,r\sin\theta\sin\phi,r\cos\theta)$), so you are just integrating $r\cdot r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\phi$ over the disc (I'm not sure whether "inverted" hemisphere means the positive-$z$ or negative-$z$ half of the sphere, so I'll leave it at that).

Comment: I think inverted doesn't matter, there would only be a change in the sign involved with flux in either case, and not in the value. Yes, $\theta$ is $\pi/2$ for $S_{2}$. But that doesn't give me a total of $\frac{5\pi r^{3}}{3}$. I had tried it out earlier.

Comment: Can you just try it out from the beginning from your end, if possible? The answer would be $\frac{5\pi r^{3}}{3}$.

Comment: Your mistake is in calculating $S_1$ integral.  See my answer.

Comment: Unit normal vector $\hat n = (0, 0, -1)$ can be written in spherical coordinates as $\hat {n} = (\sin \theta \  \hat {\theta} - \cos \theta \ \hat {r})$. As $\theta = \pi/2$, the dot product of $\vec v \cdot \hat{n} = r$.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I had made such a dumb mistake in the first part itself. Now I feel that there was no point in asking this on this forum for such a petty mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We compute
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{div}\mathbf{F}
&=\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2F_r)+\frac1{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(F_\theta\sin\theta)+\frac1{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}F_\phi\\
&=\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^3\cos\theta)+\frac1{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(r\sin^2\theta)+\frac1{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}(r\sin\theta\cos\phi)\\
&=3\cos\theta+2\cos\theta-\sin\phi
\end{align*}
So for $\mathcal{V}=\{(r,\theta,\phi)\in(0,R)\times(0,\pi/2)\times(0,2\pi)\}$,
$$\iiint_{\mathcal{V}}\operatorname{div}\mathbf{F}\,\mathrm{d}\mathrm{vol}=\frac{5\pi R^3}3$$
and
$$
\begin{gather}
\iint_{S_1}\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}=\iint_{S_1}R\cos\theta\,R^2\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi=R^3\cdot\frac12\cdot2\pi=\pi R^3\\
\iint_{S_2}\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}=\iint_{S_2}r^2\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\phi=\frac{2\pi R^3}{3}.
\end{gather}
$$

Comment: I got it now, thanks a lot. I've committed a dumb error in calculating for $S_{1}$, I realized just now :(